# Как не проигрывать медиалеер заново?

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Здравствуйте! У меня при запуске приложения в первом активити проигрывается музыка с помощью метода mediaplayer.start();. Открываю второе активити, когда нажимаю Назад и снова открывается первое активити, музыка параллельно проигрывается еще раз сначала, но музыка, которая запустилась первая, все еще проигрывается. Теперь у меня две одинаковые музыки вместе проигрываются. Я хочу, чтобы музыка, которая проигрывается первой в первом активити не останавливалась до закрытия приложения (повторялась в случае окончания). При возвращении назад на первое активити не проигрывалась сначала и параллельно. Как можно это сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы создаете новый экземпляр в методе **onResume**, поэтому оно проигрывается еще раз. Для реализации проигрывания музыки в одном Activity используйте методы **OnCreate** в котором создаете экземпляр плеера, в **onResume** делаете запуск плеера, а в **onPause** останавливаете воспроизведение, в **OnDestroy** приведен способ завершения работы плеера в случае уничтожения Activity.

Выполнять seek не требуется после **onResume**, диаграмма состояний с официального сайта и описание функций говорит о том, что воспроизведение будет продолжено после вызова start.

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, "audio file");
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mPlayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     if(mPlayer!=null){
          mPlayer.stop();
          mPlayer.release();
          mPlayer = null;
     }
}
```

[Подробнее об данном компоненте на официальном сайте Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Нет, не надо, чтобы музыка проигрывалась только на одном активити. А чтобы музыка, которая в первом активити, проигрывалась и дальше до окончания приложения, но при возвращении назад на первое активити не включалась параллельно еще раз.